# Why do I get two different results from StringLength?

Tags: string-manipulation

I spent a reasonable amount of time to find the origin of an error in a larger code segment.

```
str = StringToStream["a1;b1;c1"];

data1 = ReadList[str, Record, 1];
StringLength[data1]
{8}

SetStreamPosition[str, 0];

data2 = Read[str, Record];
StringLength[data2]
8

Close[str];
```

You can't calculate with a {8}.

Answer (score 4):

`data1` is `{"a1;b1;c1"}` and `data2` is `"a1;b1;c1"`.

And `StringLength[{"abc", "defg", "hijkl"}]` is `{3,4,5}`

It's all because `ReadList` unsurprisingly returns a list

Answer (score 4):

Because

```
data1 == {"a1;b1;c1"}
```

and

```
data2 == "a1;b1;c1"
```

#### Edit

Note that `StringLength` has the attribute `Listable`, so it will map across the items in a list.